# Creating specific process tree using fork() in C

Tags: c, linux, bash, tree

I don't know how to solve this. I need to make a process tree using `fork()`, `if` and `else` in C.
The tree needs to look like this:

```
a.out---a.out---a.out
     | 
     |--a.out---a.out---a.out
     |
     |--a.out---a.out---a.out
     |
     |--a.out
```

I already have this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main (void){
    if(fork()){
        if(fork()){}          
        else{}
        if(fork()){}
        else{fork();}
    }
    else{}

    pause();
    return 0;
}
```

which will create a process tree looking like this:

```
a.out---a.out
     | 
     |--a.out---a.out---a.out
     |
     |--a.out---a.out
```

Comment: Are you sure your code produces that second tree?

Comment: How is the diagram interpreted?  Are the children horizontal, vertical, what?

Comment: @Duck, I believe it's both. The topmost a.out has 4 children, the first of which has one child, the second and third children have a child and grandchild, and the fourth has no children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like it should do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
   if (fork()) {
      // parent
      if (fork()) {
         // parent
         if (fork()) {
            // parent
            if (fork()) {
               // parent
            }
            else {
               // child 4
            }
         }
         else {
            // child 3
            if (fork()) {
               // child 3
            }
            else {
               // child 1 of child 3
               if (fork()) {
                  // child 1 of child 3
               }
               else {
                  // grandchild 1 of child 3
               }
            }
         }
      }
      else {
         // child 2
         if (fork()) {
            // child 2
         }
         else {
            // child 1 of child 2
            if (fork()) {
               // child 1 of child 2
            }
            else {
               // grandchild 1 of child 2
            }
         }
      }
   }
   else {
      // child 1
      if (fork()) {
         // child 1
      }
      else {
         // child 1 of child 1
      }
   }

   pause();
   return 0;
}
```

Ideally, you'd add some variables storing the various PIDs, and print out them with their parents, so you could see it.

Comment: thanks the result is:
'a.out---a.out
     | 
     |--2*[a.out---a.out---a.out]
     |
     |--a.out---a.out

is it the same like i need?